# Representation of an array as a polynomial

Tags: java, string, loops, methods

What this method should do is take an array of doubles and convert them into a polynomial, for example, if the array is given was `[2.0, 3.0, -2.0]` the method's output would be `2.0x^2 + 3.0x^1 - 2.0`. What I have done is created two loops however, when I do this both outputs are separated as expected. My output looks like this `2.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 x^3 x^2 x^1`, if there is a way to have the exponents printed after the coefficient that would solve this issue.

```java
public String printPoly(Double[] doubles) {
    String polynomialString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
        polynomialString += doubles[i] + " ";
    }

    for (int j = doubles.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (j == 0) {
            polynomialString += " ";
            break;
        }
        polynomialString += "x^" + j + " ";
    }
    return polynomialString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the resultString using one for-loop.
Initialize a counter variable which you count backwards which is representing your *^3* part.
This variable starts at your *array.length-1* end runs down to zero in the iterations this is how you can create

```
4.0 x^3
2.0 x^2
0.5 x^1
2.0 x^0
```

It runs basically backwards so you should decrement it in each iteration

```
int backCounter = doubles.length-1;
```

inside your one for-loop do

```
polynomialString += doubles[j] + "x^" + backCounter + " ";

backCounter--;
```

Here is a working solution

```
package so;

import java.util.*;

public class RemoveString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] someNumbers = { 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.5 };
        String s = RemoveString.printPoly(someNumbers);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static String printPoly(Double[] doubles) {

        String polynomialString = "";
        int backwardsCounter = doubles.length - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
            polynomialString += doubles[i] + "x^" + backwardsCounter + " ";
            backwardsCounter --;
        }

        return polynomialString;
    }
}
```

Produces the output

```
2.0x^3 3.0x^2 1.0x^1 0.5x^0
```

Comment: So it turns out we do not want it to print  x^0, rather we would like to print just the coefficient, this could be done with an if statement right?

Comment: yes check for the last iteration *i == doubles.length -1* and then append only doubles[i]

Answer (score 1):

One *loop* is enough here, or one *stream*:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printPoly(new double[]{2.0, 3.0, -2.0}));
    // 2.0x^2 + 3.0x^1 - 2.0
    System.out.println(printPoly(new double[]{-2.0, 3.6, -2.1, 5.2}));
    // -2.0x^3 + 3.6x^2 - 2.1x^1 + 5.2
}
```

```java
public static String printPoly(double[] doubles) {
    return IntStream
            // iterate through the array indices
            .range(0, doubles.length)
            // string representation of the coefficient
            .mapToObj(i -> coefficient(i, doubles))
            // concatenate into one string
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

```java
// separate method because inside the lambda it is too big
static String coefficient(int i, double[] doubles) {
    String val = "";
    // take value from an array
    double element = doubles[i];
    if (i == 0) {
        // first element
        val += element;
    } else {
        // other elements
        if (element <= 0.0D) {
            val += " - " + (0.0D - element);
        } else {
            val += " + " + element;
        }
    }
    // if non-last element, then
    // raised to the power of
    if (i < (doubles).length - 1) {
        // inverted index
        val += "x^" + (doubles.length - 1 - i);
    }
    return val;
}
```